# Defining an interface for an array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm not yet familiar with Typescript, and I'm having troubles to define a simple array.

My goal is to have an array where the key is a string and its values are of types *Sound*.

I have defined an interface like that:

```
interface SoundsArrayType {
    [key: string]: Sound;
}
```

Then:

```
class SoundManager {
    private sounds: SoundsArrayType;

    constructor() {
      // error: Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'SoundsArrayType'.
      if(!this.sounds) this.sounds = [];
    }

    pauseAll() {
        for(let sound of this.sounds) {
            // error: Type 'SoundsArrayType' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
            sound.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix these errors. I read the [Interfaces page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) from the Typescript site but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript/TypeScript don't have arbitrary string keys.  The type `SoundsArrayType` is not an array but a dictionary-like object.  Don't assign `[]` to it; assign `{}` instead.  Don't try iterating over it directly; if you are using ES2017 or above, you can iterate over `Object.values(this.sounds)` instead of `this.sounds`.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, I think I confused myself with PHP arrays where you can use them as dictionaries.

Comment: The truth is subtler than I made it out to be, of course.  Arrays in JavaScript are objects, which generally do support [expando properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Expando).  So in practice you *can* add arbitrary string-keyed properties to them.  But you shouldn't *expect* an array to have such properties, and TypeScript's static type system warns you about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to have an array where the key is a string and its values are of types Sound.

This might be a good use for the [the `Map` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Here it is in TypeScript.

```js
type Sound = {
    name: string;
};

const myMap = new Map<string, Sound>();
myMap.set('dog', { name: 'woof' });
myMap.set('cat', { name: 'meow' });
myMap.set('fox', { name: 'what does the fox say?!?!' });
```

Here it is in JavaScript without the type checking.

```js
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set('dog', { name: 'woof' });
myMap.set('cat', { name: 'meow' });
myMap.set('fox', { name: 'what does the fox say?!?!' });

for (let value of myMap.values()) { 
    console.log(value.name);
}

for (let key of myMap.keys()) { 
    console.log(key);
}

for (let [key, value] of myMap) { 
    console.log(key + ':' + value.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I confused with PHP arrays which act like dictionaries. I'm going to try with Map, it seems to be the way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Sounds { // It is not an array
    [key: string]: Sound;
}
```

Then:

```
class SoundManager {
    private sounds: Sounds = {}; // Just assign an empty object to it

    constructor() { }

    pauseAll() {
        for(let key of this.sounds.keys) {
            this.sounds[key].pause();
        }
    }
}
```